# SAS EG Random Sample with variable sample size

Tags: random, sas

I need a stratified random sample that consists in a determined number of addresses. My stratification variable is the zip code.
The sample size is already pre-determined and has different number of observations per zip code. How can I incorporate the desired number ob observations per zip code? Is it possible to do this with PROC SURVEYSELECT? I have the sample size in an external file.

Example:
ZIP CODE  NUMBER_OBSERVATIONS
9999       10
8888       15
7777       10
6666       5

Is it possible? How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `sampsize` option and specify your dataset. It will limit all of the samples to each size of the strata.

```
proc surveyselect data = have
                  out  = want
                  sampsize=external
                  ;
    strata zip;
    size number_observations;
run;
```